# Error in ejabberd configuration with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I try to install ejabberd on my VPS with Debian 9, using mariadb-server.

ejabberd installed from aptitude (16.09-4).

I referred to: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/databases/mysql/

I downloaded MySQL schema with: wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/processone/ejabberd/master/sql/mysql.sql

Below is my ejabberd.yml conf file: (I removed all comment lines starting with ###)

```
loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 0
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rate_limit: 100
hosts:
  - "XXXXX.com"
  - "YYYYY.com"
  - "ZZZZZ.de"
listen: 
  - 
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.pem"
    starttls_required: true
    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv3"
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    zlib: true
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  - 
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
  -
    port: 5281
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    tls: true
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/CCCCCCC.pem"
s2s_use_starttls: optional
s2s_certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
s2s_protocol_options:
  - "no_sslv3"
auth_password_format: scram
auth_method: sql
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "MYNAME"
sql_password: "PASSWORD"
sql_port: 3306
shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000
max_fsm_queue: 1000
acl:
  admin:
     user:
       - "MYNAME@localhost"
  local: 
    user_regexp: ""  
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: admin
    - 100
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal
  s2s_shaper: fast
access_rules:
  local:
    - allow: local
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  configure: 
    - allow: admin
  muc_create: 
    - allow: local
  pubsub_createnode: 
    - allow: local
  register: 
    - allow
  trusted_network: 
    - allow: loopback
language: "en"
modules:
  default_db: sql 
  mod_adhoc: {}
      mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce
  mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {} # requires mod_adhoc
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_echo: {}
  mod_irc: {}
  mod_http_bind: {}
  mod_last: {}
  mod_muc: 
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline: 
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_pubsub: 
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    ignore_pep_from_offline: true
    last_item_cache: false
    plugins: 
      - "flat"
      - "hometree"
      - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stats: {}
  mod_time: {}
  mod_vcard:
    search: false
  mod_version: {}
allow_contrib_modules: true
```

It stopped working after editing SQL part, as was requested in documentation:
`auth_password_format: scram
auth_method: sql
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "MYNAME"
sql_password: "PASSWORD"
sql_port: 3306`

Of course schema was loaded.

When starting again ejabberd, I got a failure with this report in ejabberd.log: thanks for any help or hint to get through...

> 2018-09-02 20:24:29.684 [info] <0.31.0> Application lager started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.692 [info] <0.31.0> Application crypto started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.696 [info] <0.31.0> Application sasl started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.702 [info] <0.31.0> Application asn1 started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.703 [info] <0.31.0> Application public_key started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.708 [info] <0.31.0> Application ssl started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.713 [info] <0.31.0> Application fast_yaml started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.723 [info] <0.31.0> Application fast_tls started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.729 [info] <0.31.0> Application fast_xml started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.735 [info] <0.31.0> Application stringprep started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.739 [info] <0.31.0> Application cache_tab started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:29.834 [info] <0.31.0> Application mnesia started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:30.228 [info] <0.31.0> Application inets started on node ejabberd@vps574962
>   2018-09-02 20:24:30.245 [error] <0.61.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.61.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no function clause matching lists:map(#Fun, sql) line 1238 in application_master:init/4 line 134
>   2018-09-02 20:24:30.245 [info] <0.31.0> Application ejabberd exited with reason: no function clause matching lists:map(#Fun, sql) line 1238

Comment: Please edit your error trace so it's more readable.

Comment: Thanks Andrey for fast reaction, I edited log report above.

Comment: To be more complete, my ejabberd.yml use auth_method: sql and sql_port: 3306, plus port: 5281 for https admin (this part worked before trying mariadb)

Comment: If you just changed a few lines in the configuration file, and now it complains during start, then it probably is some problem in the configuration file. What ejabberd version? Also edit your post and put all the configuration lines that break ejabberd start.

Comment: Hi Badlop, post edited with required info, thanks for help :)

Comment: Hi all, to be more complete, it stopped working when setting up sql part

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the following indentation in ejabberd.yml

from

```
    mod_version: {}
allow_contrib_modules: true
```

allow_contrib_modules: true

to

```
  mod_version: {}
    allow_contrib_modules: true
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik, I will try your idea probably next WE: I had to revert to previous state for this week... I noticed in the original .yml file, last line is not indented.